# Order dropdown with alphabetic and numeric characters

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor

I have a dropdown in my .NET Core app that I want sorted, the following options exist:

```
Multimachine
2-machine
Longmachine
Cutter
Vshape
4-machine
Cooler
Infeedmachine
3-Machine
Mainmachine
```

I thought I could simply sort this list of options using LINQ; So I'd use the following in my controller:

`ViewModel.MachineData = ViewModel.MachineData.OrderBy(m => m.Name.ToString()).ToList();`

Whilst my razor view does this:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Machine</label>
   <select asp-for="Machine.ID" id="MachineName" class="form-control" >
      @foreach (var Machine in Model.MachineData)
      {
       <option value="@Machine.ID">@Machine.Name</option>
      }
   </select>
</div>
```

I expected the sorting to be able to handle the number/letter combination, or at least show some sorting, whilst this is the case for a few most sorting seems wrong. I get the following sorted list back:

```
Cooler
Cutter
Vshape
4-machine
Longmachine
Multimachine
Mainmachine
Infeedmachine
3-Machine
2-machine
```

Is my code faulty; or do I need to filter out my numbers? I'd like to get the alphabetic numbers first then the numeric ones; or the other way around if that's easier to realize.

Comment: Is this list the output or the debug from your sort line code?

Comment: The list is the output from my sorted line of code; when debugging the same list appears

Comment: Very weird. Something special with "Name", as it seems not to be a native string? Maybe ToString() does not return what you expect?

Comment: Ah apologies; Name is an enum, I've done sorting like this multiple times in my application, only here it doesn't seem to work

Comment: In your code you sort "ViewModel". In your page you display "Model". Is it the same?

Comment: Yes, it's the same I just create a "ViewModel" object in the controller and reference it via `Model` in the  related view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried doing it directly in the view?

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Machine</label>
   <select asp-for="Machine.ID" id="MachineName" class="form-control" >
      @foreach (var Machine in Model.MachineData.OrderBy(m => m.Name.ToString()).ToList())
      {
       <option value="@Machine.ID">@Machine.Name</option>
      }
   </select>
</div>
```

In general you code should'nt be wrong: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MxvEXb

Comment: Interesting, when sorting this in the view instead of the controller the expected output does appear! Which is great, any idea why the sorting in the view does produce the correct result and why the controller does not?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I never actually used razor pages.